# How to find the length of tuple inside a list?

Tags: python, list, tuples

There is a list filled with tuples, like

```
pairs = [('cheese', 'queso'), ('red', 'rojo'), ('school', 'escuela')]
```

How do I find the length of, like, first tuple? `len(pairs)` returns me 3 and `len(pairs[])` returns error. How do I get the length of a tuple inside the list?

Comment: Just access it: `len(pais[0])`...

Comment: That's not an `array`, that's a `list`.

Comment: @Matthias while you are correct thats just a minor quibble and semantics ... a list in python is roughly equivalent to an array in python with the exception that arrays can only hold very specific data types ... and is roughly analogous to an array in any other language

Comment: Any other language? Basic, C, C#, C++, Clojure, Pascal (and Delphi), Haskell, Io, Java, Rust, Scheme and Smalltalk don't call lists an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`len(pairs[])` raises a `SyntaxError` because the square brackets are empty:

```
>>> pairs = [('cheese', 'queso'), ('red', 'rojo'), ('school', 'escuela')]
>>> pairs[]
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    pairs[]
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

You need to tell Python *where* to index the list `pairs`:

```
>>> pairs = [('cheese', 'queso'), ('red', 'rojo'), ('school', 'escuela')]
>>> pairs[0]  # Remember that Python indexing starts at 0
('cheese', 'queso')
>>> pairs[1]
('red', 'rojo')
>>> pairs[2]
('school', 'escuela')
>>> len(pairs[0])  # Length of tuple at index 0
2
>>> len(pairs[1])  # Length of tuple at index 1
2
>>> len(pairs[2])  # Length of tuple at index 2
2
>>>
```

I think it would be beneficial for you to read [An Introduction to Python Lists](http://www.effbot.org/zone/python-list.htm) and [Explain Python's slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/pythons-slice-notation).